# Empty page after each chapter?

Tags: document-classes

After each chapter I do have an empty page (without any header or footer). I do not understand why. I hope someone may help me! Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm, footskip=10mm} % Seitenlayout
%headsep=7mm, footskip= 7mm
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} % Inhaltsverzeichnis in Times

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % Deutsche Sprachanpassung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Silbentrennung bei Sonderzeichen
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % Direkte Angabe von Umlauten im Dokument
\usepackage{csquotes}             % Apostroph-Zeichen

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} % Zeilenabstand 

\usepackage{acronym}     % Sonstiges
\usepackage{anyfontsize} % Sonstiges

%Header und Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\fancyhf{} % clear the headers
\fancyhead[R]{%
   % We want italics
   \itshape
   % The chapter number only if it's greater than 0
   \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter \hspace{0.01cm} \fi
   % The chapter title
   \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoffigures\vfill
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\listoftables\vfill

\chapter{test}
\chapter{test}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{lit}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note, that it’s not recommended to combine `fancyhdr` with KOMA-Script. You’d better use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead …

Comment: Do you want to have text on both sides of the paper, or should the text be on just one side?

Comment: Furthermore there is an option `lifof=totoc` to add the LoF, LoT to the ToC instead of manually using `\addcontentsline`. There’s also `bibliography=totoc` …

Comment: Since you are able to read german, i leave a hint so you can add your lists properly, and not the wrong way: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/4035/wie-kann-ich-verzeichnisse-im-inhalt-auffuhren

Comment: I am a bit confused, since you are using `fancyhdr` in your example, altough you asked a question where you got a `scrlayer-scrpage` solution from esdd. Why don't you use that? Why are we giving you the same advice over and over and over again? I don't even want to check if @Tobi has posted the same content about scrlayer more than once on your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default in `scrbook` chapter alway start on an odd (i.e. right in double side printing) page. Use the option `open=any` to allow a chapter start on even pages too.

```
\documentclass[
   open = any,
]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Heading}
Text

\chapter{Chapter Heading}
Text

\chapter{Chapter Heading}
Text

\end{document}
```